# Regex: Find/Delete all these specific words from one specific html tag

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I have this html tag  `<p class="text_obisnuit2"></p>` In this tag there are some words (other tags) such as `<strong>` or `</strong>`. Also `<em>` or `</em>`

Example:

`<p class="text_obisnuit2"><strong><em> My name is love. </em><strong></strong></p>`

I want to delete all `<strong>` and `</strong>` from specific `<p class="text_obisnuit2"></p>`

so the output should be:

`<p class="text_obisnuit2"><em> My name is love. </em></p>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?:<p class="text_obisnuit2">|\G(?!^)).*?\K</?strong>(?=.*?</p>)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **UNCHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?:                             # non capture group
    <p class="text_obisnuit2">    # literally
  |                             # OR
    \G                            # restart from last match position
    (?!^)                           # if not at the beginning
)                               # end group
.*?                             # 0 or more any character
\K                              # forget all we have seen until this position
</?strong>                      # <strong> OR </strong>
(?=.*?</p>)                     # positive lookahead, make sure we have </p> after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open Find and Replace.
- In Find what, type `<p class="text_obisnuit2">(<strong>)(.*)(</strong>)</p>`.
- In Replace with type `<p class="text_obisnuit2">(\2)</p>`.
- Check Regular Expression in Search Mode.
- Click Replace All.

**Explained**

We group the `<strong>` start and end tags and its content. Here the content is `\2`, so in replacing we except `\1` and `\3` only keep `\2`.

**Before Replace**:

[image]

**Replace dialog**:

[image]

**After replace**:

[image]

Comment: More precise would be /?

Comment: hello, thanks for answer. But I need to delete <strong> only from that specific html tag. So your regex should include also `<p class="text_obisnuit2"></p>`

Comment: Thanks @fratester

Comment: @JustMe check the brand new edited answer!

Comment: after replace, one `<strong>` is still there :)

Comment: How can it be? I have tested it. Including more screen shots. Check them all.

Comment: @WasifHasan He has 2 `</strong>` in his test case ...

Comment: Why are you using capture group around `<strong>` & `</strong>`? They are useless and slow down the process. And why parenteses in the replacement part?